# Can anyone explain what exactly is happening in the beginning code lines of JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I am trying to understand the jQuery source and, the beginning part is a bit confusing. I have put that section of code over here (metaphorically) with some comments. Can anyone explain what exactly is happening and why is it written like so?

```
(function(global, factory) {
   // When & how will it actually satisfy the below if condition? When I run this in chrome, this never seems to go into this condition. Nor did I find the variable 'module' defined/declared anywhere in the code.
   if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
  module.exports = global.document ? factory(global, true) : function(w) {
   // What is the 'w' parameter ? Where is it being passed ?
      if (!w.document) {
        throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");
      }
      return factory(w);
    };

} else {
  factory(global);
}(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function(window, noGlobal) {

    // jQuery Stuff!!! 
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

You should always take a look at the original not minified code that has all comments ([github: jquery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery)).

This code detects in which environment jQuery is loaded to ensure that `window` exits or can be provided [jquery/src/wrapper.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/560c0c6f995a4f7584dac5be8fe5eea114a95f69/src/wrapper.js#L21):

> ```
>   // For CommonJS and CommonJS-like environments where a proper `window`
>   // is present, execute the factory and get jQuery.
>   // For environments that do not have a `window` with a `document`
>   // (such as Node.js), expose a factory as module.exports.
>   // This accentuates the need for the creation of a real `window`.
>   // e.g. var jQuery = require("jquery")(window);
>   // See ticket #14549 for more info.
> ```